# HTML5 Tracking Geo-location Persistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, iphone, html

Is it possible to track a person's location, using HTML5's geolocation API, while his phone screen is off or while the app is in the backgroud?

Does HTML5 allow us to create a mobile app that acts like a native app? Meaning can it be stored on the user's phone and accessed like a regular app, without using tools like PhoneGap?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create native application, to make it background application.

ON iOS 4 onwards, iOS application is put on "Pause" by default, when you press central hard button. 
Even with Native iOS application you need to "Wake" the application periodically for doing some background stuff, like fetching user location.

Comment: Sorry .. I work on iOS not Android. But I guess it should be same

Comment: Is it possible to write an HTML5 app and than somehow wrap it using some framework to make it work in the background? Or do I need to learn objective-c? :/

Comment: Yes there are some frameworks available that exactly do the same. Check out Phonegap, Sencha, Kony